# Font lock mode not picking up keywords

Tags: font-lock

Emacs version 26.1, compiled on CentOS 7.5 , running ada-mode 5.3.1.

The parser works correctly, but the problem is that keywords aren't being coloured. When I run describe font on the keyword, it is not reporting the word as a keyword. Any one know where to look to correct this? It's a new thing in my new installation; worked fine on 25.1 compiled on RedHat 7.2

Note I get correct behaviour when editting Python, but not Ada.

Comment: Is `ada-mode` enabled? Is `font-lock-mode` enabled? Check with `C-h m`

Comment: Yes, confirmed.

Comment: Emacs 26.1 with `emacs -Q` and a small sample Ada file "worksforme". `begin/end/loop/return` are fontlocked and marked as `font-lock-keyword-face`. Sorry.

Comment: That's good news. I'll try and rebuild and see if there's anything else I need.

Comment: This was a bug with 5.3.1 and emacs 26.1. It's now fixed in 5.3.2 -- well done Stephen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed in 5.3.2 of ada-mode.